# Flyway conditional db migration

Tags: oracle, database-migration, flyway

I'm trying to use flyway, but I have a scenario that does not know how to resolve:

When I apply the STANDARD scripts, I have to run V1.0__create_table_TAB1.sql
When I apply the scripts to customer1, the TAB1 table is a view, and so I have to run V1.0__create_view_TAB1_to_schema1.sql.

Practically:

```
└── sql
     ├── sql_common
     │   ├── V0.0 __.... sql
     │   └── V1.0__create_table_TAB1.sql
     ├── sql_customer1
     │   └── V1.0__create_view_TAB1_to_schema1.sql
     └── sql_customer2
         └── V1.0__create_view_TAB1_to_schema2.sql
```

The scripts of sql_common folder should always be applied, but the V1.0 (create table TAB1), if I apply to the customer1 script should not be applied.
In its place is to be applied V1.0__create_view_TAB1_to_schema1.sql

How can I handle prevents this case?

Answer (score 5):

Use the following structure:

```
└── sql
     ├── sql_common
     │   └── V0.0 __.... sql
     ├── sql_regular
     │   └── V1.0__create_table_TAB1.sql
     ├── sql_customer1
     │   └── V1.0__create_view_TAB1_to_schema1.sql
     └── sql_customer2
         └── V1.0__create_view_TAB1_to_schema2.sql
```

in combination with Flyway.setLocations().

- Regular: `flyway.setLocations("filesystem:sql/sql_common",
  "filesystem:sql/sql_regular");`
- customer1:
  `flyway.setLocations("filesystem:sql/sql_common",
  "filesystem:sql/sql_customer1");`
- customer2:
  `flyway.setLocations("filesystem:sql/sql_common",
  "filesystem:sql/sql_customer2");`

This way there will be exactly 1 migration with v1.0 per case.