# Flyway: is there a means to conditionally apply scripts based on a dynamic condition (sql condition)?

Tags: flyway

Some teams in our company are currently "upgrading" some legacy projects to use Flyway. One problem is that there exists multiple installations with already available database objects (baseline).

We currently have (and definitely will have more in the future as well) a use case, where we have to create some new migration scripts, but they only should run when certain conditions about the current state of the database are met.

**For example: run this script, but only if table X in the database contains data Y**

I have already seend [Flyway conditional db migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365725/flyway-conditional-db-migration), but to me this doesn't seem like the right solution, since the condition isn't just some static environment. The condition if a migration should be executed or not should be dependent on the current live state of the database.

I myself have not much experience with Flyway, but more with Liquibase. There I would implement it like this:

```
 <preConditions onFail="WARN"> 
    <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">select count(*) from oldtable</sqlCheck> 
 </preConditions>
```

Is there an equivalent in Flyway?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, no, Flyway itself can't do this kind of conditional statement. However, since flyway just runs the scripts in order, put the conditional command within the deployment script and that will work. Flyway simply executes the scripts, so they can be customized as you need them to be.